# In pandas, how to query for a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a DataFrame that has lists as its values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'languages': [['en'], ['fr']], 'author': ['Dickens, Charles', 'Austen, Jane']})
```

I can query it for strings easily:

```
df[df['author'] == 'Dickens, Charles']
```

which correctly returns the subset of `df` that matches that criteria. But when I have cell contents that are lists, such as `languages` whose values are things like `['en']`, I can't seem to search for it:

```
df[df['languages'] == ['en']]
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 2 vs 1
```

How can I query for contents that are a list?

Comment: It's best if you provide a working example so that there is no ambiguity around what you mean and what your data looks like.  Refer to [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, revised to include a workable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might do is use `apply` method to loop through the `languages` column and then compare the items:

```
df[df.languages.apply(lambda x: x == ['en'])]
#             author    languages
#0  Dickens, Charles    [en]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use some trickery to get this to run faster.  Note that this avoids the use of `apply`.

```
# create a numpy array of lists... one list to be exact
c = np.empty(1, object)
c[0] = ['en']

df[df.languages.values == c]

             author languages
0  Dickens, Charles      [en]
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not work for me.  This solution, while it works for a small dataframe, weirdly fails on a larger one!  see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53300733/289784

Answer (score -1):

I typically use an [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) filter and pass a list as an argument.

```
lst = ['A', 'B']
df[df['column'].isin(lst)]
```

Comment: df['languages'].isin(['en']) gives `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: This is completely different from what the OP asked. His elements are lists themselves, what this answer points to is how to match multiple values.